# Switch and Pushbutton Combo

Tags: switches, button

In a circuit I'm designing I want the user to be able to switch the power off and on (with an SPST style switch), as well as depress a push-button (push-to-break) that will temporarily disable the power - effectively a reset button. Ideally I would like to combine these actions into the same physical switch. Does anyone know if such switches exist? What would I search for to find them?

Edit: I would like to combine SW1 and SW2 in the below circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgrY1V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You mean like a GFCI circuit breaker with its test button?

Comment: Yeah, I guess something mechanically similar to that, however the push button should have the inverse effect (push to break, not push to make).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the [NKK M2027](http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/MtogglesBushing.pdf) (On-On-(On) SP3T) should do what you want. Just connect the circuit to terminals 2 and 4.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed to know - I wasn't aware that (On) indicated a momentary connection. Thanks.